# $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] sends user credentials in clear text

Tags: php, forms, security

I have a form.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
    <p><label>User Name : </label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username" /></p>

     <p><label>Password&nbsp;&nbsp; : </label>
     <input id="password" type="password" name="password"/></p>

    <a class="btn" href="register.php">Signup</a>
    <input class="btn register" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

which use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`.

On submitting (POST) the data, the users credentials are sent in plain text (shown below)

[image]

Where as if I replace the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` with say a "check_login.php" there isn't a problem.

I used the acunetix scanner too which also says "User credentials are sent in clear text".

I need to use the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but without the credential being shown.

Comment: And what's the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`? The scanner warning probably means that you should use HTTPS instead of HTTP.

Comment: @vitozev, value? PHP_SELF, returns the filename of the currently executing script. I did use HTTPS too ... same problem.

Comment: @votozev, I tried using the above form with this too. if ((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'on')) {
    header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}

Comment: If u must use php_self,  please escapulate before using it

Comment: It’s obvious that your browser can see what it’s sending. You should see the communication on TCP/IP level with something like Wireshark.

Comment: @Andrew, i will, the code is on the local server but thank you for the reminder.

Comment: @Gumbo, hmm, I'll download and check. I understand that the browser can see what it sends but acunetix vulnerability scanner pointed out this as well.

Comment: Using PHP_SELF results in a relative URI, which especially means that it’s only HTTPS if the requested form URI was also HTTPS.

Comment: Also you need to `htmlspecialchars()` any content you echo into an HTML context.

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfy your question? If so, could you please mark one as correct to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

The vulnerability alert you are receiving is being displayed because the web server is making use of `HTTP` rather than `HTTPS` when the client is sending the user credentials.

This would not have anything to do with your PHP form—regardless of how you implement it, the information is still being sent in clear text. Example:

```
POST /userinfo.php HTTP/1.1
Host: testphp.vulnweb.com

uname=test&pass=test
```

You can see the `uname` and `pass` parameters being sent in plain text and can be intercepted and read by anyone.

For more information, I would encourage you to read the answer of the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146146/is-my-form-password-being-passed-in-clear-text).

Whilst we're at it, you might also want to check out [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Acunetix](https://www.acunetix.com/) should you want to keep yourself extra secure ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the problem, and misunderstanding `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`.

Firstly, your actual problem has nothing to do with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, nor with your form nor PHP. The problem is because your site is not secured with HTTPS. If you're using HTTP, then everything the browser sends or receives is sent in plain text and can potentially be intercepted. If you want your traffic to be secure then you need to use HTTPS instead. This is something you configure in your server, and is entirely separate from anything in your PHP code.

Secondly, you state "I need to use the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`...". This is not actually true: you *don't* need to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in this context. `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is a global variable in your PHP program that contains address of the current page. So if you visit `userinfo.php` within your site, then the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` will contain `/userinfo.php`. This is the value that you're putting into the form's `action` attribute. That's fine, but understand that you don't actually *need* it in this context, because the default value of `action` is to submit the form back to the current page. In other words, your form will work exactly the same if you omit `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` entirely. This isn't in any way related to your security warning, but I felt it was important to clarify what's going on here, to help you understand that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` isn't some magical thing that makes the form work; it's just a string variable with a pagename in it.